How do I print all lines from the first line of a file up to and including the first matched line?
How do I print all lines from the first line of a file up to and including the first matched line?
Is awk better for this?

sed '/PATTERN/q' FILE

-tip: jmlemetayer and Mikel
awk solution:
awk '{print} /PATTERN/{exit}' FILE

-tip: Ed Morton


How do I print all lines from the first line of a file up to and
including the first matched line?

I would harness GNU AWK for this task following way
awk 'NR==1,/pattern/' file.txt

Explanation: This solution uses Range which start at 1st line (number of row equal 1) and stop at /pattern/. If file.txt does not contain pattern whole line will be printed.
(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)
